# Ejecutar trigger con in if

Tags: sql-server

tengo el síguete trigger que captura el log de una bd

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_ActualizarLog_tblmvto_lotes] 
On [PORCIPOS].[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] 
AFTER  update AS 
DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) 
SET @ipPC = (
    SELECT client_net_address 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
    WHERE session_id = @@spid  group by client_net_address
)  
SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF; 
insert into Destino .[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] (
animal, CantEtiquetasContador, CantInv, ciclan, codlote, codtipo, DCTOSAP, fecha, fechacava, FechaEnvioSacrio, 
FECHASAP, granja, id, LLAVESAP, M, marcaventa, Muesca, NumeroOrejas, NumeroTesticulos, observaciones, 
peso, pesocaliente, pesocava, pesociclan, pesofrio, pesopie, remision, rendimiento, sexo, Sin, TipoCanal, 
valorcanalcaliente, valorcanalfrio, valorcanalpie, valorkilocaliente, valorkilofrio, valorkilopie ,
[TRANSACCION1], [FECHATRANSACCION1],    [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1],C_ejecutada ,Puesto_T
) 
(
select top 1 animal, CantEtiquetasContador, CantInv, ciclan, codlote, codtipo, DCTOSAP, fecha, 
fechacava,  FechaEnvioSacrio, FECHASAP, granja, id, LLAVESAP, M, marcaventa, Muesca, 
NumeroOrejas, NumeroTesticulos, observaciones, peso, pesocaliente, pesocava, pesociclan, 
pesofrio, pesopie, remision, rendimiento, sexo, Sin, TipoCanal, valorcanalcaliente, valorcanalfrio, 
valorcanalpie, valorkilocaliente, valorkilofrio, valorkilopie, 'ACTUALLIZACION' AS transaccion, 
getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION, SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION, @ipPC, 
(
    SELECT  
    details.text FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests requests 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details 
    WHERE   requests.session_id > 50 
), 
HOST_NAME() as esta  FROM INSERTED 
) 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
```

en una tabla de configuraciones tengo un campo tipo bit llamado **CONFIGLOG** lo que yo necesito es que si ese campo esta en 1 se ejecute el trigger si esta en 0 que no lo ejecute es decir que antes que el trigeer se dispare haga esa condición

algo así  `IF(SELECT CONFILOG FROM [dbo].[tblconfiguracion] <>1)`

No se ejecute y salga el mensaje trigger apagado

Si es 1, pues que se ejecute

Comment: Una aclaración, si hay trigger, a menos que lo elimines, siempre se ejecuta, lo que puedes hacer es condicionar la ejecución del código del mismo.

Comment: Eso es lo que trato de hacer

Comment: La repuesta de Roger entiendo responde tu pregunta

Comment: Sería mucho mejor si dieras formato a tu código en vez de simplemente estructurarlo en prosa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te decía, el trigger siempre se ejecuta. Otra alternativa, podría ser salir prematuramente, cuando detectamos la condición de no generar la auditoría:

```
ALTER TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_ActualizarLog_tblmvto_lotes] 
On [PORCIPOS].[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] 
AFTER  update AS 

IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [dbo].[tblconfiguracion] WHERE CONFILOG <> 1)
BEGIN
    return
END

-- Acá sigue el código actual del Trigger
```

Comment: Gracias, fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizar el `IF` al inicio y poner un `return` cuando no se cumpla la condición.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_ActualizarLog_tblmvto_lotes] 
On [PORCIPOS].[dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] 
AFTER  update AS 

DECLARE @CONFILOG = (SELECT TOP 1 CONFILOG FROM [dbo].[tblconfiguracion])
IF (CONFILOG = 0)
BEGIN
    return
END
...
```